# GLSL link error

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am currently ripping my hair out in frustration about the errors I get while trying to compile GLSL shaders, I have successfully managed to compile both shaders, but when it comes to linking them i get an error. There is no output, but the linking failed.

Here is the compilation+linking code:

```
GLuint program = NULL;
GLint compile_ok = GL_FALSE, link_ok = GL_FALSE;

GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vertCont, NULL);
glCompileShader(vs);
glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_ok);
char logBuf[1024];
int len;
if (0 == compile_ok)
{
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vs, sizeof(logBuf), &len, logBuf);
    LogMgr::logMessage(LogMgr::CRITICAL, "Error in vertex shader\n", logBuf);
    return false;
}

GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fragCont, NULL);
glCompileShader(fs);
glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_ok);
if (!compile_ok) 
{
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vs, sizeof(logBuf), &len, logBuf);
    LogMgr::logMessage(LogMgr::CRITICAL, "Error in fragment shader", logBuf);
    return false;
}

glAttachShader(program, vs);
glAttachShader(program, fs);
glLinkProgram(program);
glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &link_ok);
if (!link_ok) 
{
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vs, sizeof(logBuf), &len, logBuf);
    LogMgr::logMessage(LogMgr::CRITICAL, "Could not link basic shaders!", logBuf);
    return false;
}
return program;
```

And here is the vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 330

out vec4 outputColor;
void main()
{
   outputColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i didn't create the program object. I added this line of code befor linking and it worked:

```
program = glCreateProgram();
```

Answer (score 7):

Your calls to getShaderInfoLog are wrong. You're always checking the compile log for the vertex shader. This explains why you're not seeing any error message. And that's what you get for copying and pasting code ;)

For the fragment shader, it should be:

```
glGetShaderInfoLog(fs, sizeof(logBuf), &len, logBuf);
```

And for the link status:

```
glGetProgramInfoLog(program, sizeof(logBuf), &len, logBuf);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that now, i forgot to change that thing xD

Comment: Ok after i changed it, this is what i get as the linker error:[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|[|

Now that does NOT look good :S

EDIT: Here is a link to a picture showing the REAL error text (i could not copy it in the same way it was written) https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38127392/Untitled.png

Comment: Could you update the code in the question to what you have now?

Comment: looks like you're not passing the length `len` you get back from `glGetProgramInfoLog` to `LogMgr::logMessage`, so you're probably printing random garbage rather than the actual error...

Comment: No, when i got compilation errors on the shaders earlier it  outputted the correct information.